# How to converting Http to HttpClient in Angular 5 (or >4.3)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient

I have a working code using Http and I would like to learn how to convert this to use the latest HttpClient.

I have done the following steps:

- in App.module.ts: import { HttpClientModule } from
  "@angular/common/http";
- add HttpClientModule into the imports array
- in the below service file (see below): import { HttpClient }
  from "@angular/common/http";
- Inject HttpClient instead of Http in the
  constructor (replace Http with HttpClient.

Now, the following steps I can't get correct (how to rewrite `return this.http.get(queryUrl)..`)

Any ideas?

...

Code working using **Http**:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { SearchResult } from "../models/search-results.model";

export const YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyCIYsOjnkrIjZhVCFwqNJxe1QswhsliciQ";
export const YOUTUBE_API_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search";

@Injectable()
export class YoutubeSearchService {
  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_KEY) private apiKey: string,
    @Inject(YOUTUBE_API_URL) private apiUrl: string,
  ) {}

  search(query: string): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
    const params: string = [
      `q=${query}`,
      `key=${this.apiKey}`,
      `part=snippet`,
      `type=video`,
      `maxResults=10`,
    ].join("&");
    const queryUrl = `${this.apiUrl}?${params}`;

    return this.http.get(queryUrl).map((response: Response) => {
      return (<any>response.json()).items.map(item => {
        // console.log("raw item", item); // uncomment if you want to debug
        return new SearchResult({
          id: item.id.videoId,
          title: item.snippet.title,
          description: item.snippet.description,
          thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the updated code

Comment: The new HttpClient automatically assumes you are returning json, so there is no need for `response.json()` anymore. I would recommend reading the docs (https://angular.io/guide/http). It should have everything you need.

Comment: what error you are getting or what is the problem you face?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Response types are now controlled by `responseType` option, which defaults to `json`. This eliminates `.map((response: Response) => response.json())` line.

`HttpClient` methods are generic, and response object type defaults to `Object`. The type can be provided for stronger typing:

```
return this.httpClient.get(queryUrl).map(response => {
  return response.items.map(
    item =>
      new SearchResult({
        id: item.id.videoId,
        title: item.snippet.title,
        description: item.snippet.description,
        thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
      }),
  );
});
```

It is beneficial to rename service instance to `httpClient` to avoid confusion with `Http` instances.

After when you want to use the service, you subscribe to it.

Lets say youtube is the injected YoutubeSearchService in the component.

```
  queryYoutube() {
    this.youtube.search("Rio de Janeiro").subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

Comment: Hi @estus, thank you for your answer! I created a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/u00pvkvs/1/) for the changed code, please see here: I followed your suggestion, please see here:
// Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Here is a link of a json response https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=Rio%20de%20Janeiro&key=AIzaSyCIYsOjnkrIjZhVCFwqNJxe1QswhsliciQ&part=snippet&type=video&maxResults=10

Comment: That's what the answer explains. Consider providing a proper type like ISearchResultItems . You can use `any` of course but this will elminte type safety.

Answer (score 1):

In angular 5 you can use the .map function inside the .pipe twice to do the same thing as in the previous angular version:

```
getCoinRankings () : Observable<Coinobject[]>{
  return this.http.get<Coinobject[]>(this.coinmarketcapAPI)
    .pipe(
      map(x => x.map(data => new Coinobject(data))),
      tap(coinrankings => console.log(`fetched coinrankings`)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getCoinrankings',[]))
    )
}
```

x = the request.json() -> the whole json response
data = the individual item in the json array.
In my example I used a constructor that would manually map the json to the required properties, but you can also do it with like this.

```
return this.httpClient.get<Object[]>(queryUrl).pipe(
    map(response => response.map(data => new SearchResult{
        id: item.id.videoId,
        title: item.snippet.title,
        description: item.snippet.description,
        thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
      })),
    tap(...),
    catchError(...)
    )
}
```

Not that the user of a decrepated module would hurt your application offcourse... (but feel free to correct me)